# Capslock OFF in Batch - alternatives

Tags: vbscript, batch-processing, batch-file

I would like to know if I can use the same code below and do some minor changes to add a  functionality I need. The way it is written :

```
::::Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
::::WshShell.SendKeys "{capslock}"
Set WshShell = Nothing
findstr "^::::" "%~sf0" > temp.vbs & Cscript //nologo temp.vbs & del temp.vbs
echo Capslock is off
```

RESULT :

- It activates the CAPS ON, if it is already off
- It activates the CAPS OFF, if it is already on

I would like to change it to **always OFF**. How can I make this slight correction in the code ?

Thanks

Comment: @Greg Beech: The problem is that if the user has his capslock off already, the above code will turn the caps on. I want the caps always off. However I also want to use the VBS embedded in my batch.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Word.Application is used by this VBS to query the CAPS state. If CAPS is ON, then we turn it off.

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set objWord = CreateObject( "Word.Application" )

if objWord.CapsLock <> 0 then
   ' turn capslock off
   objShell.SendKeys "{capslock}" 
end if
objWord.Quit
```

To keep everything in one batch file, we generate a temp .vbs file, execute and delete it to make sure that CAPS is OFF.

```
set BAT_HOME=%~dp0
echo %BAT_HOME%
cd %BAT_HOME%
echo Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") > temp.vbs
echo Set objWord = CreateObject( "Word.Application" ) >> temp.vbs
echo if objWord.CapsLock ^<^> 0 then >> temp.vbs
echo objShell.SendKeys "{capslock}" >> temp.vbs
echo end if >> temp.vbs 
echo objWord.Quit >> temp.vbs
cscript //nologo temp.vbs
del temp.vbs
echo ... do your thing in the batch file
```

Comment: I could not make your VBscript work. It should be embedded in my batch so as to not have two files (*.VBS and my *.bat). Could you please write the whole procedure (Batch -> VBs -> Batch)? The error I obtain is that "<" was unexpected at the moment.